# call to function in javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript

need your help again... for javascript :)
see below the code..

```
           var x=input;
            var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
                 {
                    username=input;
                    check_username.call();
                 }
             else
                 {
                     email=input;
                     check_email.call();
                 }
```

and the actual function goes below... (just a sample start of the pgm)

```
 function check_username()  
      {
          if (username!="")
          {
              var xmlhttp;    
              {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
```

the call to the function works well with Chrome and Firefox. But doesn't get triggered with IE 8 :(
i get the error message - object expected... can you please share me the code i need to use - for calling function. thanks again! :)

Comment: What part of your code produces the error message?

Comment: [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) expects several parameters.  The first one is the object that should be treated as the `this` variable.  Pass something, maybe even `null` as an argument, and you may avoid your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
check_username.call(this);
```

and

```
check_email.call(this);
```

Comment: thanks Scott and Dave.. i will check and share you my output :)